# Dynamically loading multiple Google Analytics on GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Is it possible to load Google Analytics dynamically by passing the tracking ID through the dataLayer? I have tried to push() the tracking ID and read out the variable in GTM but analytics doesn't seem to fire.

I have an ecommerce site and want to load the sellers tracking ID on different product pages. Ideally the seller would load their tracking ID via a dashboard instead of me having to add it manually to GTM.

Some pages e.g the cart complete page could have multiple analytics loaded as the customer may have purchased products with different sellers.

Any thoughts or pointers?

Comment: At which point during the page load did you push? If you GA tag is set to fire on page load, and you push the id later then the tag cannot fire since the id will not be set. If so, you need to fire your tag later or move your push above the GTM code.

Comment: You can create a `Lookup Table Variable` and map it with conditions to send data to different GA properties

Comment: Push to dataLayer not only tracking ID but also an event with any name (in this same push of course). Then just configure google analytics tag which will fire only on that event with tracking id grabbed from dataLayer variable. Or do like Eike said: move your push above GTM in code and fire GA tag for example on page load.